# Как узнать общий объем ОЗУ в системе?

Tags: java, ram

Смотрел в javadoc. Там написано, что в java 1.5 можно получить оперативку в системе через 
`ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getTotalPhysicalMemorySize()`
Но этого метода у меня просто нет... 
Как получить общее значение оперативной памяти в системе, используя java 1.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так. Подходит для JVM

```
long memorySize = ((com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory
        .getOperatingSystemMXBean()).getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
```